# setWindowSize() · WebdriverIO adding 1px by itself - Tests failing due to this

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to test break points of web application, hence I am setting the window size to certain breakpoints, but the for some reason 1px is added on the width that I specified, and the tests are failing.

Here is the webdriverio log file, which clearly states that the specified width is 975px, but the result is 976.

[image]

Anyone, had similar issue?

Comment: what happens if you set it to 974? Did you check it?

Comment: Checked, then it's okay, but it is inconsistent for other scenarios, sometimes it adds more than one pixel.
So I was advised adding a custom command on gitter channel. There was a function in webdriverIOv4, and u can add it by using wdio custom command, here is the link to official documentation: https://webdriver.io/docs/customcommands.html

Comment: I am using custom commands for other reasons. but the native command should work without any issues as well. Did they ask you to raise any issue on GitHub so that they can look at it?

Comment: Lately got notified about your comment, sorry. 
No, I haven't raised any issue on GitHub. 
Meanwhile I tried by adding custom command which looked like this:  

`browser.addCommand("setViewportSize", function (width, height, x, y) {
      const diff = browser.execute('return ({width: window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth, height: window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight});');
      const vw = width + diff.width;
      const vh = height + diff.height;
      browser.setWindowRect(x || null, y || null, vw, vh);
      });
`
But again I am facing the same issue (1px difference) :(

Comment: Funny to mention here is that the test is working on browserstack, just causing the issue when running on local instance of browser.

Comment: Do you have the latest chrome?

Comment: Yes, I was not able to run the tests, cause I had Chrome 80, and the latest is 81.
webdriver-manager was giving me a headache installing chromedriver that supports Chrome 80 so I updated the Chrome to the latest one.